# How do i delete a class node with pointer chidren

Tags: c++, class, pointers, binary-tree, header-files

I am having errors deleting the private member class called `tree2`, I have tried to use `"**"`, `"&*"`, `"*&"` but I just keep getting error after error.

**header file:**

```
class tree1
{  
    private:
    class tree2
       {
         tree2*child;
         tree2**child2;
         int data;
        };
    void clear( tree2** the_root);
    tree2* root;
};
```

I am the one who has put the clear function there.So I go in the `.cpp` file and implement it this way:

```
void tree1::clear(tree2** TheRoot)              
{
   if(*TheRoot == NULL) { return; } 

   clear(&(*TheRoot->child1));                                                      
   clear(&(*TheRoot->child2));

   delete TheRoot;          
   TheRoot = NULL;
}
```

then in a function that used clear,  i call it as   `clear(root)` or `clear(&root)` or `clear(*root)` or `clear(&*root)`.All combinations have failed, i keep getting erros. What is the right way to delete this class ?

Answer (score 1):

As it seems you want your `root`-Pointer to be `NULL` after deletion. That is the reason why just passing `tree2*` as a parameter is not sufficient and the `tree2**` is necessary.

The line `delete TheRoot;` will not delete root, but a pointer to root (which was not allocated via `new` in your example, thus causing some hidden error. The same problem is in the next line. You can solve this by writing `delete *TheRoot; *TheRoot = NULL;`.

But since you are using C++, you can pass `tree2*&` like so:

```
void tree1::clear(tree2*& TheRoot)              
{
   if (TheRoot == NULL) { return; } 

   clear(TheRoot->child1);                                                      
   clear(TheRoot->child2);

   delete TheRoot;    
   TheRoot = NULL;
}
```

and call it like `clear(root);`

Comment: this os what i had at first, the computer goes into a segfault. gdb  points to the if statement.

Comment: If the `tree2` pointers inside `tree2` are not correctly intialized (e.g. to `NULL`) you might get that segfault. Try to set them to `NULL` explicitly in the constructor of `tree2`.

Answer (score 0):

you need to call it with clear(&root) if you want to modify the value.  In side, you do *root = null to clear it.

Comment: i get error if i call like clear(root), compiler says cannot initialize a parameter of type ** with an lvalue of type *

Comment: that's what I'm saying, call it like clear(&root), don't forget the &.

Answer (score 0):

It is sufficient to use just `tree2` and `tree2*` (pointer to a `tree2` type) data types, do not use `tree2**` (pointer to a pointer of ..).

Do not expect the pointed by element to be `NULL`, but set the pointer value to `NULL` and just check the pointer values to decide if they point to allocated memory or not.